# Voice input (speech-to-text) for Amazon Connect workflows

Tags: amazon-connect

Is there a way to configure Amazon Connect to prompt a caller to accept voice input? I know that it supports [DTMF input](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/amazon-connect-with-amazon-lex-press-or-say-input/), but I'd like to be able to speak input as well, perform speech-to-text interpretation, and use that as input to an AWS Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Connect integrates with Amazon Lex bots for voice input.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-connect-and-amazon-lex-integration/)